# Use grep to match a pattern in a line only once

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I have this:

```
 echo 12345 | grep -o '[[:digit:]]\{1,4\}'
```

Which gives this:

```
1234
5
```

I understand whats happening. How do I stop grep from trying to continue matching after 1 successful match?

How do I get only

```
1234
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do the grouping: `\(...\)` followed by the exact number of occurrence: `\{<n>\}` to do the job:

```
maci:~ san$ echo 12345 | grep -o '\([[:digit:]]\)\{4\}'
1234
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!!

Comment: This syntax means **up to 4** matches  per line. OP wanted **at most 1** match per line, which would be `grep -o '\([[:digit:]]\)\{1,1\}'`

Answer (score 10):

Do you want grep to stop matching or do you only care about the first match. You could use [`head`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/head/) if the later is true...

```
`grep stuff | head -n 1`
```

Grep is a line based util so the `-m 1` flag tells grep to stop after it matches the first *line* which when combined with head is pretty good in practice.

Comment: This works! But how do I really stop grep from matching after first match if found? Just curious.

Comment: -m does not stop grep from matching after 1st match is found.

Comment: At first I edited my answer to include the -m flag which is what you already had in your question, ug. Using -m 1 will limit the searching to just the first line found and head will filter which should be pretty good in practice.

Comment: My question is for matching a pattern in a line only once. I removed -m 1 from my question. Can I stop grep from matching a pattern in a line after first match is found? I am just curious to know if this could be done.

Comment: I don't think you can. It's going to work on the entire line. Any particular reason you care? You could use perl if this is a show stopper for you.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sed` instead of `grep`:

```
echo 12345 | sed -n '/^\([0-9]\{1,4\}\).*/s//\1/p'
```

This matches up to 4 digits at the beginning of the line, followed by anything, keeps just the digits, and prints them.  The `-n` prevents lines from being printed otherwise.  If the digit string might also appear mid-line, then you need a slightly more complex command.

<s>In fact, ideally you'll use a `sed` with PCRE regular expressions since you really need a non-greedy match.  However, up to a reasonable approximation, you can use:</s> (*A semi-solution to a considerably more complex problem...now removed!*)

Since you want the first string of up to 4 digits on the line, simply use `sed` to remove any non-digits and then print the digit string:

```
echo abc12345 | sed -n '/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]\{1,4\}\).*/s//\1/p'
```

This matches a string of non-digits followed by 1-4 digits followed by anything, keeps just the digits, and prints them.

Comment: `sed 's/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]\{1,4\}\).*/\1/p;d'` maybe a little less busy?

Answer (score 0):

If – as in your example – your numeric expression will appear at the beginning of the string you're starting with, you could just add a start-of-line anchor `^`:

```
echo 12345 | grep -o '^\([[:digit:]]\)\{1,4\}'
```

Depending on which exact digits you want, an end-of-line anchor `$` might help also.

Answer (score 0):

grep manpage says on this topic (see chapter 'regular expressions'):

```
 (…)

 {n,}

      The preceding item is matched n or more times. 

 {n,m}     

      The preceding item is matched at least n times, but not more than m times. 

 (…)
```

So the answer should be:

```
 echo 12345 | grep -o '[[:digit:]]\{4\}'
```

I just tested it on cygwin terminal (2018) and it worked!