# Using regex to obtain the first IP?

Tags: regex, grep, ip

How can I use regex to return just the first dst IP from this data?

```
ipv4     2 udp      17 34 src=192.168.1.76 dst=192.168.1.254 sport=198 dport=53 packets=1 bytes=65 src=192.168.1.254 dst=192.168.1.76 sport=53 dport=198 packets=1 bytes=105 mark=0 use=2
```

Wanted result: 192.168.1.254

What I have tried:

```
dst=([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}
```

This returns both the 1st and 2nd dst IPs.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/anONgm/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this question was worded as just "How can I return just the first dst IP from this data?", then the answer would simply be this with GNU awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/dst=([^ ]+)/,a){print a[1]}' file
192.168.1.254
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/dst=[^ ]+/){print substr($0,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-4)}' file
192.168.1.254
```

That will work with any sed in any shell on any UNIX box.

btw verifying a regexp using some online tool just proves you have a regexp that works in that online tool. It's generally not useful for creating regexps to run in some other tool as they all use different regexp flavors (e.g. BRE vs ERE vs PCRE) with their own restrictions and/or extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try taking all characters until a whitespace. Check this;

```
dst=([\S]+)
```

Comment: How can I make this only return the first dst=? This returns both of them.

Comment: I don't get it. This should return 192.168.1.254 at index 1.

Comment: He's getting two IPs returned because there are two locations where `dst=` can be found (and your pattern matches both of them). @Tod you need to turn off the `g` modifier (which returns all matches instead of returning only the first match)

Comment: @ctwheels How do I turn off the g modifier using regex/grep? I know it can be turned off on the website. Is it disabled by default unless /g is included?

Comment: @Tod one of these posts may be of assistance: [Use grep to match a pattern in a line only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543201/use-grep-to-match-a-pattern-in-a-line-only-once) **or** [Grep only the first match and stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093452/grep-only-the-first-match-and-stop)

Comment: @ctwheels Thanks, do you know how to incorporate a look-around assertion on the dst= part to exclude this in the result so I can get just the IP alone as requested in the original question?

Comment: @Tod the answer provided will capture the IP into a group so that you can access it that way. Otherwise `(?<=dst=)(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b` will work (you don't need all the fluff but it will match an IP address correctly the way it's written). It works as a positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes the token is there (but without capturing it).

Comment: The negation of `\s` is `\S`, it's not necessary to write `[^\s]`.

Comment: @EdMorton Do you know how to use a non-capturing group in grep regex? `(?:dst=)([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}` gives me an error. I don't want to include the "dst=" string in the result just the IP.

Comment: No, I never use `grep -P` (as required for that regexp to work) since [the man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Basic-vs-Extended) says use of `-P` is `highly experimental` and you simply don't **need** it so idk why anyone would use it. If you want to know how to get specific output from specific input using UNIX tools rather than how to write a specific regexp then post a new question.

Comment: @Tod I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46125292/1745001) based on how to do what I think you're trying to do rather than how to write an abstract regexp that could be used in some unspecified tool with some options for some purpose... Hope it helps.